# How to assign new rights (ACL) to existing registry key without inheriting rights from parent

Tags: c#, windows, registry, acl

New rights can be set using `RegistryKey.SetAccessControl(new RegistrySecurity(...))`. But after that the `inheritance is turned on`.

Is there a way to assign new rights without turning the inheritance on?

The whole code:

```
void test
{

    SecurityIdentifier sidAccUser = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
    NTAccount ntAccUser = sidAccUser.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;

    RegistryAccessRule regAcRule = new RegistryAccessRule(
      ntAccUser
    , RegistryRights.FullControl
    , InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit
    , PropagationFlags.None
    , AccessControlType.Allow);

    RegistrySecurity regSecurity = new RegistrySecurity();
    regSecurity.AddAccessRule(regAcRule);

    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"ZZTEST", true);

    // after that the inheritance is turned on
    regKey.SetAccessControl(regSecurity);

}
```

I found this solution but don't want to use a COM-Server: [Setting permissions and blocking inheritance from C# with SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/setting-permissions-and-inheritance-from-csharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetAccessRuleProtection` to protect the DACL from inheritance..

```
regSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
```

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @boboes, it is on the `ObjectSecurity` class because it applies to the object as a whole not the individual `AccessRule` or `ACE` .

Comment: what I mean is that I would have expected it as a parameter of regKey.SetAccessControl(..., true, false) and not as a seperate method.

Comment: @boboes, .Net does it like that because that's how the underlying system does it. It's part of the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` structure. The .Net classes are just wrappers around the native functionality.