# Save and Restore Registry Access Rights and Inheritance

Tags: c#, registry, acl

Is there a way to `save` and `restore` the access rights for `one key` or do I have to run through all ACEs and inheriting and do it manually?

```
{  
    SaveRights(regKey);

    // ... do some changes


   RestoreRights(regKey);

}
```

Comment: First of all you should ask yourself why you are even asking the question. Why are you messing with registry security in the first place?

Comment: I have to modify the rights and change the values. afterwards the environment should be restored to the previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually.

Basics:
[RegistryAccessRule Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cs50ebzk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Problems with enabling / disabling inheriting: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676812/how-to-assign-new-rights-acl-to-existing-registry-key-without-inheriting-right)

Setting the owner: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455691/registrysecurity-access-is-denied-c-sharp)